# Would there any be a case when only one sided tests would be applicable. Could the collection of the data signal this?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Would there any be a case when only one sided tests would be applicable. Could the collection of the data signal this?

Is there a way when I could tell from the collection of the data that I would only use a one-sided hypothesis test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hypotheses are statements you are interested in. Whether a hypothesis should be formulated as one or two sided depends on how you translated your research question to testable hypotheses. Sometimes, the choice is easy as there may be some logical boundary making one sided or two sided tests impossible. Often, that is not the case. So, the answer to your question is: No. You will have to go through the process of formulating your research question, and derive hypotheses from that. There is no way to automate that: computer cannot tell you what you should be interested in.